# How do I make EF Code First Data Annotations work with MVVM?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm

This is probably an incredibly stupid question.

In MVVM tutorials, a model would look something like this:

```
public class Case : ObservableObject
{
        private int caseID;
        public int CaseID
        {
            get { return _caseID; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _caseID)
                {
                    _caseID = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("CaseID");
                }
            }
        }
```

In Entity Framework Tutorials, you get something like this:

```
public class Case
{               
    [Data Annotation]        
    public int CaseId { get; set; }
}
```

**Now the stupid question:** If you try to put them together, where does the data annotation go?

**Like this?**

```
public class Case : ObservableObject
{
    private int caseID;

    [Data Annotation] ????
    public int CaseID
    {
        get { return _caseID; }
        set
        {
           if (value != _caseID)
              {
                  _caseID = value;
                  OnPropertyChanged("CaseID");
              }
        }
}
```

Or are you not supposed to put them together like that at all? If not, what do you do?

(If it matters, I'm more interested in using the Code First Data Annotations to define a 1:0-1 FK relationship than Data Validation right now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would still place the DataAnnotation on the property, even if you're using custom getters/setters, since EF interfaces with your entity through properties.

Fields are generally intended to be private to the class.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the last sentence?

Comment: I was referring to the general design principles regarding [fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229057(v=vs.110).aspx) and [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Sorry, I meant what, in my example, prompted you to mention it?

Comment: I was guessing that you weren't sure where to put the attribute, because you thought it might go on the field. I was explaining why EF wouldn't look at fields.